# SetFormula Not Working with Import Range in Google Apps Scripting

Tags: import, scripting, set, range, formula

Looking for help with SetFormula in Google Scripts.  I want it to Import a Range, but only once a day, not all the time.

Why does this simple setformula work well:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet7');[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("G18");
cell.setFormula("=SUM(G15:G17)");
}
```

But can't seem to get the IMPORTRANGE to work right on this (ID hidden):

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet7');[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("G24");
cell.setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4dS..../edit#gid=1211665645","Sheet7!A1:D8")');
}
```

When I use the Import Range formula here directly in a cell, everything comes in perfectly.  Just trying to automate this through script triggers. I would then copy the values off and delete the Import formula.  I don't want a continuous ingest, just one time transfer from another Sheet.

I'm not getting any scripting errors on my coding, though I am not a coder by trade.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, sorry.  I'm too new to Google Scripts.  Never changed myFunction names, and didn't realize it would execute the first one open, and I had many tabs going.

Sorry, don't answer.  The good news is that the code actually works well.